# Dictionary comprehension for swapping keys/values in a dict with multiple equal values

Tags: python, python-3.x, swap, dictionary-comprehension

```
def invert_dict(d):
    inv = dict()
    for key in d:
        val = d[key]
        if val not in inv:
            inv[val] = [key]
        else:
            inv[val].append(key)
return inv
```

This is an example from Think Python book, a function for inverting(swapping) keys and values in a dictionary. New values (former keys) are stored as lists, so if there was multiple dictionary values (bound to a different keys) that were equal before inverting, then this function simply appends them to the list of former keys.

Example:

```
somedict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'doubletwo': 2, 'three': 3}
invert_dict(somedict) ---> {1: ['one'], 2: ['doubletwo', 'two'], 3: ['three']}
```

My question is, can the same be done with dictionary comprehensions? This function creates an empty dict `inv = dict()`, which is then checked later in the function with `if/else` for the presence of values. Dict comprehension, in this case, should check itself. Is that possible, and how the syntax should look like?

General dict comprehension syntax for swapping values is:

```
{value:key for key, value in somedict.items()}
```

but if I want to add an 'if' clausule, what it should look like? `if value not in (what)`?

Thanks.

Comment: typically the way of shortening that `invert_dict` code is to use `setdefault` or a `defaultdict`.  I'm not aware of any way to write this in a dict comprehension, and suspect that any means of doing so is going to be completely unreadable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append to a dict of lists with a dict comprehension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276473/append-to-a-dict-of-lists-with-a-dict-comprehension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a set comprehension side effect:

```
somedict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'doubletwo': 2, 'three': 3}

invert_dict={}
{invert_dict.setdefault(v, []).append(k) for k, v in somedict.items()}

print invert_dict
# {1: ['one'], 2: ['doubletwo', 'two'], 3: ['three']}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible with simple dict comprehension without using other functions.

Following code uses [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group keys that have same values.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> {k: [x[1] for x in grp]
     for k, grp in itertools.groupby(
         sorted((v,k) for k, v in somedict.iteritems()),
         key=lambda x: x[0])
    }
{1: ['one'], 2: ['doubletwo', 'two'], 3: ['three']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good answer:

```
fts = {1:1,2:1,3:2,4:1}

new_dict = {dest: [k for k, v in fts.items() if v == dest] for dest in set(fts.values())}
```

> Reference: Head First Python ,2nd Edition, Page(502)