# Alternative way to use setdefault() using dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a nested dictionary that was created from a nested list where the first item in the nested list would be the outer key and outer value would be a dictionary which is the next two items. The following code is working great using the two `setdefault()` functions because it just adds to the nested dictionary when it sees a duplicate key of the outer. I was just wondering how you could do this same logic using a dictionary comprehension?

```
dict1 = {}
list1 = [[1, 2, 6],
         [1, 3, 7],
         [2, 5, 8],
         [2, 8, 9]]
    
for i in list1:
    dict1.setdefault(i[0], {}).setdefault(i[1], i[2])
```

OUTPUT:

```
 {1: {2: 6, 3: 7}, 2: {5: 8, 8: 9}}
```

Comment: Just stick with the loop. This is a task for which comprehensions are awkward and extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the loop because it's very readable and efficient. Not all code has to be a one-liner.

Having said that, it's possible. It abuses syntax, extremely unreadable, inefficient, and generally just plain bad code (don't do it!)

```
out = {k: next(gg for gg in [{}] if all(gg.setdefault(a, b) for a,b in v)) for k, v in next(g for g in [{}] if not any(g.setdefault(key, []).append(v) for key, *v in list1)).items()}
```

Output:

```
{1: {2: 6, 3: 7}, 2: {5: 8, 8: 9}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried to achieve that result and failed. 
The comprehension overwrites the new entries.

After, giving this idea a look, I found a similar post in which it is stated it is not possible:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276473/append-to-a-dict-of-lists-with-a-dict-comprehension

I believe Amber's answer best sumarizes what the conclusion with my failed attempt with dict comprehensions:

> No - dict comprehensions are designed to generate non-overlapping keys with each iteration; they don't support aggregation. For this particular use case, a loop is the proper way to accomplish the task efficiently (in linear time)